# git - push current vs. push upstream (tracking)

Tags: git

I have read the git man about push command, but I still don't understand the EXACT difference between *current* and *upstream* to be set in the **push.default**

I want that our team will just do push, and only changes on the branch that they are currently working on, will be pushed.
As I understand, this branch is the one that marked with * (star) when I do **git branch**.

Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The question is *what* are you pushing, and *to where*:

- **`current`**:

  - "**what**" is only your current branch (no other branches),
  - "**to where**" is a branch of the same name (created if it doesn't exist) in the **[upstream repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739376/definition-of-downstream-and-upstream/2749166#2749166)**.
- **`upstream`**:

  - "**what**" is also only the current branch,
  - "**to where**" is to whatever branch (not necessarily of the same name) on the upstream repo [has been assigned as an upstream branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11012861/6309) for the local branch you are pushing.

As [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6547682/6309), Git2.0 will additionally introduce a new default for `push.default`: **`simple`**

**`simple`** is like **`upstream`**, but the upstream has to have the same name as well or the push will fail.

---

Pushing only one branch (with the mode "`simple`", "`current`" or "`upstream`") avoids [the scenario](http://jimkubicek.com/blog/2012/08/16/git-push-current-branch/) where all matching branches are pushed (mode "`matching`", which was the default for a long time), even though some of your branches might not be ready to be pushed.

```
(master)> git push
...
To git@github.com:jkubicek/my_proj.git
   21b430d..dd378ca  master -> master
 ! [rejected]        release -> release (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:jkubicek/my_proj.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. 
hint: If you did not intend to push that branch, you may want to
hint: specify branches to push or set the 'push.default' configuration
hint: variable to 'current' or 'upstream' to push only the current branch.
```

---

The difference between the two (`current` and `upstream`) is in the **pull** (what to pull from the remote to your branch?):

- pushing "`current`" doesn't mean that your current branch `B` has `remote/B` has its upstream branch.
  Ie: `branch.B.merge` isn't set, when your are pushing the "`current`" branch.
  Ie: when pulling to `B`, git won't know what branch to pull.
- pushing "`upstream`" means that your current branch `B` has `remote/B` has its upstream branch.
  Ie: `branch.B.merge` *is* set, when your are pushing the "`upstream`" branch.
  Ie: when pulling to `B`, git knows what branch to pull (as well as which remote repo: `branch.B.remote`)

Comment: `push.default` has no influence on `pull`! – Right would be to say that the configuration of an upstream branch has an influence on what is pulled. But both things (upstream and push.default) are two different things.

Answer (score 8):

`push.default` is best covered in the man page of git config (`man git-config`).

To understand the difference between “upstream” and “current” for `push.default`, you should know the term *upstream*:

Upstream is a local pointer from a normal local branch to a local remote-tracking branch. (Yes, these are all local.) Examples:

- branch *blabla* has *origin/blabla* configured as upstream (very common)
- branch *blabla* has *origin/foo* as upstream (branch has a different local name; not so common)
- branch *blabla* has *origin2/foo* as upstream

Note that *origin/** branches are local and (re-)set on each fetch from origin. These are called “local remote-tracking branches”. They represent the state of the branches on the remote “origin” at the time of the last fetch.

Each (normal) local branch can have an upstream configured, but this is no must: the configuration of an upstream relationship is only for convenience for some git commands!

If you do a `git status` for example, git tells you “x commits behind/ahead” if it knows the upstream (so git can compare to it).

A normal initial `git checkout blabla` usually sets up the upstream configuration for you (if origin/blabla exists, it is checked out and setup as upstream – otherwise the checkout fails).

`git push` can also use the upstream configuration of a branch, i.e. to copy your new commits over to the remote branch which represents upstream.  (This is `push.default = upstream`.)

`push.default = current` lets a `git push` copy the new commits over to the remote *under the same name*. It completely ignores the upstream configuration. – If your local branch name is always the same as the remote one, both configurations have the same effect, except that `git push` with `push.default = upstream` will fail, if upstream is not configured yet.

PD: Yes, `*` in the output of `git branch` shows the current branch.

Comment: @ebelisle The man page is called git-config, but on the systems I work with, it can also be opened with `man git config`. What system do you have?

Comment: I'm using macOS high Sierra, git 2.20.1 installed by brew.  "man git-config" works for me, but "man git config" gives me the man page for just git.  Our mileages vary.