# Git branches: tracking upstream

Tags: git

I don't know if I'm misusing Git, or if I've got a configuration problem.

I clone my Github repos onto machine A and B, then on machine A I do:

```
git checkout -b branchA
// make edits
git add .
git commit -am "initial"
git push
```

then on machine B I do:

```
git pull
git checkout branchA
// make edits
git commit -am "edits"
git push
```

on machine A I then do:

```
git pull
```

However it says:

```
There is no tracking information for the current branch
```

so I have to do:

```
git branch --set-upstream branchA origin/branchA
```

Why do I have to set the upstream, when it originally pushed it to origin/branchA without problem?

I'm using msygit 1.8. on Windows.

P.S. when i do the `pull` on machine B, why isnt the new branch `branchA` tracked by default? `git branch` doesnt show it (but it does with `-r`). Can I make all new remote branches be tracked by default when i `pull?`

Comment: What is the output of `git config push.default` in your repository?  It wouldn't happen to be `current`, would it?

Comment: it doesnt return anything (on machine A) :/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

since `git config push.default` doesn't return anything, that means, with "git 1.8.0.msysgit.0", your `git push` means `git push origin :`, with the refspec '`:`' standing for "matching" branch.

Here it creates a matching `branchA` on the remote side.

But that doesn't make it a remote tracking branch.
In other word, `branch.branchA.merge` isn't set to anything.
This is why the git pull fails: it doesn't know what remote branch it is supposed to merge to local `branchA`.

---

Note, your first `git push` should have displayed the following message:

```
warning: push.default is unset; its implicit value is changing in
Git 2.0 from 'matching' to 'simple'. To squelch this message
and maintain the current behavior after the default changes, use:

  git config --global push.default matching

To squelch this message and adopt the new behavior now, use:

  git config --global push.default simple

See 'git help config' and search for 'push.default' for further information.
(the 'simple' mode was introduced in Git 1.7.11. Use the similar mode
'current' instead of 'simple' if you sometimes use older versions of Git)
```

So, with Git2.0, that git push will fail.
The only way to push `branchA` will be by setting explicitly its upstream branch (using the same name):

```
git push -u origin branchA
```

Comment: that makes sense, thanks. So is there a config setting to prevent this behaviour (i.e. make the `git push`/`git push origin :` create a remote tracking branch?) or do i always have to `push -u`?

Comment: @AndrewBullock you should use `-u` for the first push. After that, you don't need it. Also setting the default push mode to simple help enforcing that correspondence between a local branch and a remote tracking branch.

Comment: @AndrewBullock that said, the upstream mode can help you here, if you don't want to use `-u` explicitly: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/13751847/6309