# Prevent that git pushes to all branches

Tags: git

I would like to prevent that git push and pull to all remote branches. I know the switch --all and I would expected that git will only pushes to all when I set this switch.

When I enter **git remote show origin** than I see that all my local branches are configured for git pull and push to the remote branch.

But I would prefer it, that git will only pushes the actual branch when I enter **git pull** without **origin branchname**.

Is there a config switch with that I can change this behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering the new [default push policy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10002469/6309), you can try and set:

```
git config push.default upstream
# or
git config push.default simple
# or
git config push.default current
```

All three are only for pushing the *current* branch.

As I explain in "[git - `push current` vs. `push upstream` (tracking)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13751847/6309)":

> Pushing only one branch (with the mode "`simple`", "`current`" or "`upstream`") avoids the scenario where all matching branches are pushed ("default "`matching`"), even though some of the branches are not ready to be pushed.