# How to push to new git branch not with Xcode

Tags: xcode, git

I've been using a git branch with a remote repo as well (Bit bucket)

I decided to create a new branch so ran this code

```
Directory= ~/tmp/merge/aaa> git branch iOSUI/beta
Directory= ~/tmp/merge/aaa> git checkout iOSUI/beta
Switched to branch 'iOSUI/beta'
```

Then tried to push

```
Directory= ~/tmp/merge/aaa> git push origin iOS7UI/beta
error: src refspec iOS7UI/beta does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://xxx/repo.git'
```

So I tried to create a remote branch

```
Directory= ~/tmp/merge/aaa> git branch origin iOSUI/beta
error: there are still refs under 'refs/heads/origin'
fatal: Failed to lock ref for update: Is a directory
```

After that failed I tried through XCode by selecting push and then it pushed successfully to

> 'origin/iOS7UI/beta'

Again I tried through the command line 2 options

```
Directory= ~/tmp/merge/aaa> git push origin iOS7UI/beta
error: src refspec iOS7UI/beta does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://xxx/repo.git'

and this option with the '/'

Directory= ~/tmp/merge/pixtr> git push origin/iOS7UI/beta
fatal: 'origin/iOS7UI/beta' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Answer (score 1):

The [recent default push policy "`simple`"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13751847/6309) would prevent you to push to a non-existent branch (unless it is set to be your [upstream branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1070851/6309)).

You would need to do:

```
git push -u origin iOS7UI/beta
```

But check first if the branch from which you have created your `iOS7UI/beta` is pushed or up-to-date compared to the [upstream repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2749166/6309).
If it is behind, that means `iOS7UI/beta` is based on a parent SHA1 which isn't yet pushed to origin.