# can't set 2 local branches to the same upstream remote

Tags: git

lets say I have 2 branches 
1. BranchOne
2. master - his remote branch is origin/master

I tried to make the remote of BranchOne to be also origin/master but it doesnt let me and it gives me the option to create a remote origin/BranchOne and then make a pull request
 Is it not possible to set both local branches upstream to the same remote ?

Comment: The only restriction on `git branch --set-upstream-to=<upstream> <branch>` is that both `<upstream>` and `<branch>` must exist in the local Git repository. Show your actual commands and error messages (cut and paste the text of the commands). See [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: I am on my local branch want the origin of it to be origin/master 

git branch --set-upstream-to origin master 
Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'origin'



However when I push it created a remote branch which is named my localBranch name

Comment: The upstream setting of a branch has relatively little to do with the push action. Your set-upstream-to operations have worked; it looks like you've asked the wrong question.

Comment: I want to push the local branch to origin/master and not create a remote branch named local branch name.. what do I need to do ?

Comment: It looks like the question you intended to ask is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13751319/1256452).

Comment: @torek  had it correct except for a small change in command. `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master` It should be `--set-upstream-to=origin/master` instead of `--set-upstream-to=origin master` That should do the trick. Please note that after this all pull and push will happen on master of remote.

Comment: @Vishwanath: based on his comments, his example command was just an example: none of these branches are actually named `master` so therefore that is not the actual `git branch --set-upstream-to=...` command he typed in. In any case the issue is with the *push* operations. Git 2.x defaults to `push.default` set to `simple`. MD10 must have it set to something else, such as `current`, or be using a Git version predating 2.0.

Comment: Thats some new learning for me. Thanks for that. I just tried the command and realised that having space in the upstream value creates the issue; then tried it with slash for upstream value on my local repo as a test. That worked as expected. Thinking he might have got the same issue so tried clearing that confusion.