# Eclipse Egit automatically pull changes to local branch

Tags: eclipse, git, repository, branch, egit

My repository has only one branch HEAD. My local branch is master and I'm usually checked out on my local branch. Now when I pull it won't update my local master. I have to right click on master -> merge, then select remote branches -> HEAD and then updates will be on master too. I went around Internet for hours but I can't seem to understand branch system or how these refs work. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong and how can I fix it? 
And sometimes it pushes a new master branch. (creates a new branch itself)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My repository has only one branch HEAD

But HEAD isn't a branch. It represents what will be committed, but it can be a [detached HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309).

See more at "[EGIT branches local vs Remote tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8218067/6309)", where you can see an history with no HEAD

[image: detached head in Egit]

---

The other explanation is when your `master` branch has no [upstream branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6244487/6309) [associated to it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11012861/6309).

You need to:

- [configure the upstream push](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Configuring_upstream_push)
- [specify the refspec associated to your local tracking branch](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Repository_Configuration)

[image: http://wiki.eclipse.org/images/thumb/e/e2/RepoMgrRemoteConfig.png/800px-RepoMgrRemoteConfig.png]

That will fetch any branch from the remote repo and put then in the `refs/remote/origin` namespace.